# Applying a simple function over a vector using vapply

Tags: r, function, vector

This question is somewhat two-fold. First, I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve a simple implementation of a function over a vector. Second, I'm trying to understand the meaning of FUN.VALUE in vapply.

I've defined a simple halfwave rectification function:

```
Fun = function(x) x[x<0]=0
```

I then define a vector:

```
A = -10:10
```

I wish to apply this function to the vector. I've tried a number of approaches, but can't figure out how to do it easily.

I could always do

```
A[A<0]=0
```

but that defeats the purpose of using a function.

I've tried defining the function so that it applies to each element of the vector, rather than the vector as a whole:

```
Fun = function(x) {if (x<0) {x=0} }
```

I can't use apply, since apply only seems to work when the object that you're applying the function to has dimensions, and a vector doesn't have dimensions in R for some reason.

If I use lapply, I get NULL, or 0 for each element of the output object, depending on which of the two above functions I use.

For vapply, I can't make any sense out of the documentation for FUN.VALUE

Here's what it says:

> FUN.VALUE
>   a (generalized) vector; a template for the return value from FUN. See ‘Details’.

and in Details:

> vapply returns a vector or array of type matching the FUN.VALUE. If length(FUN.VALUE) == 1 a vector of the same length as X is returned, otherwise an array. If FUN.VALUE is not an array, the result is a matrix with length(FUN.VALUE) rows and length(X) columns, otherwise an array a with dim(a) == c(dim(FUN.VALUE), length(X)).

This makes no sense to me. In my case, A is a vector with 20 elements, and clearly I want the output to be a 20 element vector. So how do I specify a generalized 20 element vector template? And wouldn't the length of such a template be 20, and not 1?

I'd really appreciate some help here. I'm finding the documentation to be incredibly frustrating, and it's hard to tell whether it's because I'm missing something obvious, or whether the documentation is vague.

Comment: `FUN.VALUE` simply specifies the return value type.  Normally this is not necessary, but it can catch certain types of errors.  You pass in an object of the correct type, such as `character()`

Comment: If I don't specify anything for FUN.VALUE, I get an error:

**Error in vapply(X, Fun) :  argument "FUN.VALUE" is missing, with no default**

Comment: If you don't want to specify `FUN.VALUE` use `sapply` instead.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLundberg, I was able to get it to work with sapply by using the following function:

Fun = function(x) {if (x<0){x=0} else x=x}

I'm curious though, how would I achieve the same result using vapply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has a bug in it. Instead of

```
Fun = function(x) x[x<0]=0
```

You actually want:

```
correct_fun = function(x){
  x[x<0]=0
  return(x)
}
```

As is, your function is not returning anything at the moment. It modifies `x` but doesn't return it so it just dies with the function. Executing `correct_fun` on `A` I get:

```
[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```